# How do I pass an argument to the handler of Event.observe?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, arguments, prototypejs, dom-events

`prototype.js` has the following function

```
Event.observe(document, "dom:loaded", foo_function);
```

It waits for the `document` to finish loading before executing `foo_function`. How do I pass an argument to `foo_function`? Something in the likes of

```
Event.observe(document, "dom:loaded", foo_function, {arg1: bar_argument, arg2: baz_argument})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Event.observe(document, "dom:loaded", (function(e, bar_argument, baz_argument) {
    //now bar_argument = bar,and baz_argument = baz
}).bindAsEventListener(this, bar, baz));
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who use `element.observe` and extracted named functions for cleaner code:

```
(function main() {
    let myInteger = 0;
    document.observe('dom:loaded', onDOMLoaded.bindAsEventListener(this, myInteger));
})()

function onDOMLoaded(event, integer) {
    alert(integer);
}
```